# data tables aodata.push converting array to comma separated list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a web application that is using jquery DataTables with an ajax callback to search/sort the data serverside. I am pushing some supplementary with data using `aoData.push`. One of the data values is the value of a multi-select box, so it is a javascript array, so the push looks like

```
aoData.push({name:"multiselect",value:$('#multiselect').val()});
```

In `DataTables 1.9.1`, in the GET params to the ajax request, `multiselect` ends up as a comma separated list, ie

```
&multiselect=1,2,3
```

I have updated to version 1.10, and now the value is actually getting sent as an array:

```
&multiselect[]=1&multiselect[]=2&multiselect[]=3
```

I would like it to go back to being a comma seperated list, since that is what the server side `php` code is expecting, and I don't have access to that.

I changed nothing in my HTML or DataTables initialization, I simply updated the `jquery.dataTables.js` include file to the newer version.

**How can I tell DataTables to send my multiselect data to the server as a comma separated list, instead of an array?**

Comment: In your fnServerData() callback can you convert the $('#multiselect').val() to a comma separated list and then pass that into aoData?

Comment: yes, but since the functionality changed when I upgraded I figured there would be a property i could set

Comment: This issue may be not related to DataTables. Instead it may have occurred due to jQuery upgrade, see `traditional` setting in [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can force datatables 1.10 to use the 1.9 style of sending server params by setting `$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true`.

http://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side#Legacy

Comment: I tried this before and after my dataTables declaration and it didn't work. I am also using the `sAjaxSource` parameter as suggested by the link and it didn't work. I think I just need to split the array manually.